# How can I read a large set of data from a file into either a pointer to a structure or array of a structure in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, debugging, structure

I have a data file with a known key, that is, it has many entries (devices) with the same properties and I have this structure in code to capture it.

```
struct deviceData{
  int id;
  char serial[10];
  float temperature;
  float speed; 
  long timestamp; 
}

struct deviceData fileItems;
```

It's 4 bytes for the ID, 10 bytes for the serial code, 4 bytes for both the temperature and speed and 8 bytes for the timestamp. 30 bytes in total.

What I would like to achieve is to be able to read all those entries and run a calculation in the quickest way I can.

What I initially thought of doing was to simply create a giant array to capture all the entries but that causes errors.
Secondly I thought of allocating space from a pointer to that structure and reading the whole file to that. That worked in execution but I had trouble processing the data. Possibly a gap in fundamentals on my part.

The way I'm currently looking at is to loop through readings where I capture a single entry using fread(), process that and then move the file to put the next entry into the buffer.
Something like this:

`fread(&fileItems, 30, 1, filename)`

What happens though is that when I view what actually gets read I see that the ID and the serial code were read correctly but the following data points are garbage. Reading a little bit about it I came across something about padding which I don't fully understand but the fix seems to be to make my char array 100 which seems to work for the first entry but I suspect it's causing problems with subsequent readings because it's throwing my calculations off.

I'm kind of at a wall here because every strategy I try seems to have something that works strangely. If I could at least be pointed in the right direction I'll at least know I'm putting effort in the right thing.

Comment: How is the data stored in the file. Is it raw binary? Text? If raw binary can you provide a hex dump (of for example) of a few recirds

Comment: Have you checked whether the structure will take up 30 bytes of space or not? Check out [Structure Alignment](https://www.eventhelix.com/embedded/byte-alignment-and-ordering/) for more info.

Comment: make sure to open the file in binary mode (assuming the file contains raw data), in your struct use types with known, correct sizes. You probably also want to make your struct packed

Comment: So the hex data would be...

```01 00 00 00 4E 46 32 43 2D 37 49 56 33 00 41 B3 33 33 42 86 FA E1 52 92 C5 61 00 00 00 00```

And then if you parse that you get id: 1, serial: NF2C-7IV3, temp: 22.4, speed: 67.49, timestamp 1640338002. Then the next one starts the same with ID too and the value 2

Comment: @lulle what do you mean about a packed struct?

Comment: When it is not packed, the compiler might insert padding to align the members properly. So the struct layout might not match the data you have stored in the file

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to process a group of data record by record, you probably can utilize the methodology of defining a structure, then reading the data from a file into the structure, and then processing the data.  To make things consistent, it would make sense to store the data as a structure in a binary file.  Following is a code snippet creating some sample data and then processing it following the spirit of your project.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct deviceData{
  int id;
  char serial[10];
  float temperature;
  float speed;
  long timestamp;
};

struct deviceData fileItems;

void create_data(char * file_name)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(file_name, "wb");
    if(!fp)
    {
        printf("\n\tFile open error\n");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        fileItems.id = i + 20000 + i * 3;
        sprintf(fileItems.serial, "SN%d", fileItems.id);
        fileItems.temperature = 166.0 + i;
        fileItems.speed = 2400.0;
        fileItems.timestamp = 20220830;
        fwrite(&fileItems, sizeof(struct deviceData), 1, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

void read_data(char *file_name)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");

    if(!fp)
    {
        printf("\n\tFile open error\n");
        return;
    }

    while(fread(&fileItems, sizeof(struct deviceData), 1, fp))
    {
        printf("ID. . .  . . . .: %d\n", fileItems.id);
        printf("Serial number. .: %s\n", fileItems.serial);
        printf("Temparature. . .: %f\n", fileItems.temperature);
        printf("Speed. . . . . .: %f\n", fileItems.speed);
        printf("Timestamp. . . .: %ld\n", fileItems.timestamp);
    }
}

int main()
{
    create_data("device.dat");      /* Create some sample data to be read      */
    read_data("device.dat");        /* Read and print the data to the terminal */
    return 0;
}
```

The storage of device data probably would occur in some other monitor program, but for this snippet a one-off function was included to produce some data to process.

Analyze that code and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: Thanks this is great and I really would like it to work this way as it makes a lot of sense to me.

Now when I look at `sizeof(struct deviceData)` it's not the same as the data entry chunks I want to capture each time. So the reason I've come to learn is that C adds padding in memory and the way around that seems to be to order the struct from largest variable to smallest but that messes with the way I'm reading the file. 

Is there a way around this or do I need to change my approach? And then how should I change it?